Why does a block in Substrate-based blockchain have no author and no reward points?
We encountered an issue in our Substrate-based blockchain network where a block has no author and no reward points were given to any validator. This block was finalised. The block was an era-transitioning block where the era changed from 1 to 2. According to the logic, the validator set from era 1 should have produced this block. However, examining the digest logs of the block, it appears that it was produced by one of the validators from the era 2 validator set. Consequently, the explorer does not show an author for this block, and no reward points were assigned.
Details

Substrate Version: polkadot-1.7.1
Node Implementation: Avail v2.0.0.0-rc4
Network Setup: Era 1 had only 1 validator, Era 2 had 8 validators

Attempts to Resolve

Checked validator logs for errors/something unusual - none found.
Reviewed network conditions - no significant issues detected.

Questions:

How can a validator from era-2 produced a block in era-1?
Why did validator from era-1 accepted this block? (since it has signed the justification for this block & looking into its logs it did not tried producing the block for this slot)
Why was the reward points for this block not given to anyone?
What steps can I take to diagnose and fix this issue?

